# PHP - Combining Websocket Client & Server (Relay)

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I want to create a PHP script that connects to a websocket server and then serves the responses from the remote server on a local websocket server. Basically, a websocket relay. I have working client code and I have working server code.

The problem comes when I try to combine the client with the server. I've tried taking my client code and putting it in my server code. It works except that the client is blocking so that if I disconnect from it, I can't reconnect. It happens like this:

I start my code -> server code opens local port and serves websocket -> I connect to local port with websocket testing tool -> client code connects to remote websocket server and relays responses to me -> I disconnect my tool -> client code never returns so server code can't accept new connections anymore.

My code uses the following composer packages:

```
"cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.0",
"ratchet/pawl": "^0.3.1"
```

You can see that I have commented out the client part that connects to the remote websocket server. This is the part that blocks.

```
<?php


// Make sure composer dependencies have been installed
require '../web/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once('../web/usersc/includes/custom_functions.php');

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use WebSocket\Client;

/**
 * chat.php
 * Send any incoming messages to all connected clients (except sender)
 */
class MyChat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        /*
        $loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $reactConnector = new React\Socket\Connector($loop, [
            'dns' => '8.8.8.8',
            'timeout' => 10
        ]);
        $connector = new Ratchet\Client\Connector($loop, $reactConnector);

        $connector('wss://example.com/websocket', [], ['Origin' => 'http://localhost'])
            ->then(function(Ratchet\Client\WebSocket $conn) {
                $conn->on('message', function(\Ratchet\RFC6455\Messaging\MessageInterface $msg) use ($conn) {
                    echo "Received: {$msg}\n";
                    //$conn->close();
                });

                $conn->on('close', function($code = null, $reason = null) {
                    echo "Connection closed ({$code} - {$reason})\n";
                });

                $conn->send('Hello World!');
            }, function(\Exception $e) use ($loop) {
                echo "Could not connect: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
                $loop->stop();
            });

        $loop->run();
        */
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from != $client) {
                $client->send($msg."sdfsfsf");
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

// Run the server application through the WebSocket protocol on port 8080
$app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
$app->route('/chat', new MyChat, array('*'));
$app->run();
```

Comment: I have a similar issue and a similar setup. There is a Browser-Client that sends sockets messages to a ratchet php socket server and this socket sever also acts as a client (with ratchetphp/Pawl) to send / forward messages to a node.js socket server. Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: Oh wow I forgot about this. I've become so much more familiar with websockets since I posted it that I could create a relay in no time. I don't remember why I wanted to do this. These days I would just use Python. If you're dead-set on PHP, I recommend starting with the most bare-bones websocket example or lib you can find an just do all the work yourself. Websockets are super simple. Just use PHP's socket extension: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php